# What is the mathematical basis behind using a chirp signal to determine the resonant frequency of a second order differential system?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, resonance, chirp

It is a common practise for engineers to try to determine the resonant frequency of a system through a chirp signal.

Given a damped oscillating system with displacement $x$, driven by a chirp signal force, the equation of motion is given by:

$$\ddot{x} + 2\beta \dot{x} + \omega_0^2 x = A\cos\omega(t) t \, ,$$

where for a linear chirp frequency, $\omega(t)$ is given by the following:

$$\omega(t) = const \cdot t + t_0$$

The practise is to examine the amplitude of the system in the frequency space, with the frequency at the largest amplitude being equivalent to the resonant frequency of the system.

What is the mathematical reasoning behind this technique?

EDIT:

I have tried to solve this problem analytically. Please look at this link for details:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835621/how-do-i-solve-the-second-ode-ddotx-2-beta-x-alpha2-f-cos-omegat

Comment: I'm imagining a student at a lab bench, hand on the "Frequency" knob of a sine wave generator feeding a series RLC circuit, and turning the knob to increase the frequency while watching the amplitude of the current waveform, looking for a maximum.  Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: Some instruments come with a pre-programmed linear chirp signal, the FFT of the mechanical movement is then analysed, and the position of the peak is taken to be the resonant frequency